# Dialog being dismissed when activity restarts

Tags: android, android-activity

When I rotate the device when a dialog is shown, my activity is recreated and the dialog gets dismissed. Do I need to show the dialog again each time the user rotates the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity is restarted when you rotate the device. You can stop this by adding this to your application part in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: What if my activity goes to the background some way (by clicking home, for example) and gets killed by the OS? I want to keep the dialog shown when the user returns.

Comment: You should use the various functions of the application lifecycle (onPause, onDestroy, etc) to set a boolean, and when the onReturn etc is called, check for this boolean and restart the dialog.

Comment: This was the solution I thought about, but I didn't like it very much. I thought Android had a better way to deal with it.

Comment: Well, this is quite a good way. You have a certain state, and you want to save that state, and return to it when you start again. It is some extra work for the developer, but it means lots of good things for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Flavio,

You can prevent your Activity from being recreated on orientation changes by adding the following in your AndroidManifest.xml:

`<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="YourActivity"/>`

Then you need to override the following method in your code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flavio: I am unable to recreate the problematic behavior with alertDialogs or custom dialogs on orientation change. Are you using onCreateDialog and showDialog(int id)? According to the docs "the dialog will be automatically saved and restored if you use showDialog. This is my experience.

It is even possible to create an XML layout with an editText widget, inflate the layout, and the state in the editText will be automagically saved on orientation change.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater= getLayoutInflater();
final View myView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
builder.setTitle("About");
builder.setMessage(alertMessage+"Version: "+versionName);
builder.setView(myView);
AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
```

I have code [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/dialogs) and [here](http://sites.google.com/site/jalcomputing/home/mac-osx-android-programming-tutorial/custom-password-dialog) with screen captures that demonstrates the persistence of the alertDialog and custom dialog on orientation change